# PCB markings and reverse engineering a board

Tags: circuit-analysis

I've got a fried board for an elliptical exercise machine and I'm looking to build my own replacement as there is no repairing or replacing the original. I have interfaced successfully with everything on the machine except the heart rate sensors on the handles. They go back to a small board that is elevated off the main board by some headers. I'm hoping to remove this small board and add it to the new computer but I can't seem to get it working. There is a row of 4 pins labeled - E O +.

My scope doesn't detect anything communication wise and tracing them out shows me that O goes through a resistor to a capacitor then ground. E goes directly to the main board CPU and looks to be pulled low by a 300k. The sensor pads go to 3 different pins that I'm not concerned about. The brain of this small board is one of those bare chips hiding under a black glob so I have no idea what it is..

Positive and negative are obvious, but E and O have me puzzled. Does anyone have any ideas what these might be? When powered they have a voltage increase but nothing happens when my hands are on the sensors.

Comment: Site rules: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* - and the reason is that nobody knows what your circuit under the black blob is nor what it interfaces to nor with what voltage levels.

Comment: What Andy said, plus  a remark: seeing if anything happens can depend greatly on how and with what you measure. Have you got an oscilloscope?

Comment: E= 3V and O = 2V

Comment: And oddly enough this time when I put my scope on I am seeing a clear digital pulse with my hands on the pads. Guess I need to analyze this

Comment: Turned out it is actually fairly simple. With no hands on the pads the O pin (Output I presume) sits at 3V. When hands are on the pads it drops to 0V and gives a ~300ms pulse for every heartbeat. The pulse itself is 3V so I can use it on an interrupt. Still unsure what the resistor and capacitor are for on the E pin but I will add them to the board.